# Disabling input box using Jquery makes all the attribute return as null

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

Using .NET MVC3 and Jquery, I have a checkbox toggling whether an input box is readonly or not. However, when it is set to a readonly mode, it passes the value of the field as null to controller. My Jquery code is below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
     $(":text").attr('readonly', true);
     $(":checkbox").not(this).attr('readonly', true);
 } else {
     $(":text").attr('readonly', false);
     $(":checkbox").not(this).attr('readonly', false);
 }
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: try using disabled = false and see if it solves.

Comment: nope. not working. tried disabled = true, and enabled = false

Comment: You could store the value in a HiddenFor instead and use your JS to update it based on the checkbox changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

```
  <input type="checkbox" id="SomeID"/>
    <input type="text" id="txt"/>
```

javascript code :

```
$(function(){
    $('#SomeID').click(function() {
        $("#txt").attr('readonly',this.checked);
    });
});
```

demo : [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dtc4h/1/)